How might I explain to my HR that, despite being physically able/fit to work, that I can't return to work due to my surgery and job demands?
I work in a school as a student supervisor. I took some time off work for reconstructive surgery to remove and replace a problematic implant. I informed my work that I would be out for 6 to 8 weeks, but I had hoped to return sooner. While my recovery was initially smooth, I have recently experienced complications similar to those from my last surgery. HR has requested an exact return date and a certified letter from my healthcare provider stating I am fit to return.
Would I need to share the type of surgery in order to avoid possible repercussions? Due to the complications, I am considering taking the full eight weeks, but this would also depend on if my surgeon says that I'm able to return or not.
I've taken measures to provide additional support for that area (my groin) to prevent further issues. Returning to work with noticeable bulges there while supervising elementary school students would neither be comfortable nor appropriate.
If my surgeon clears me to return earlier than 8 weeks, how should I handle this? Do I have to share these personal details, or can I communicate my need for more time without facing legal repercussions or punishment?

Welcome Elias to the WorkPlace SE site! Can you add a country tag so answers are more targeted. Labor laws differ per country

"HR has requested an exact return date and a certified letter from my healthcare provider stating I am fit to return." - what if they get a letter stating you are not yet fit? Perhaps they simply want to plan who covers your work and how long that must happen? "I work in a school as a teacher." - There may be a time when doctors state you "fit" or "not fit" depending on individual conditions and how you feel - they don't know that if you don't tell them. Did you discuss with your doctor about being fit to return there now? You definitely should.

I don't know why this has downvotes and even flags. It looks like a perfecty fine question to me, just needs a country tag. If you have concerns, that I do not see, please raise a specific moderator flag and explain your concern.

"Despite being physically fit/able to work, I can't return to my work due to my surgery..." seems contradictory, can you help clarify that?

You told them 6 to 8 weeks. They've planned for 8 weeks, you can be sure of that. You had hoped for less than 6 but now are facing the reality that surgery can be quite a big thing and not something you just breeze past. You have no reason to believe your doctor is going to clear you to work before you're ready, but you want us to help you convince your employer your doctor is wrong, all while keeping the precise nature of the surgery to yourself? Is that the question, because it feels like that's the question.

This question dances the line between what we can answer and what we can't.
There are two components to the question:
1: Medical Exemption.
The short answer here is if the Doctor says you are okay to work, then medically speaking you are okay to work. Obviously you can discuss this with your Doctor about any concerns, issues etc. and then the Doctor can make an informed decision.
2: Appropriateness to return to work.
This is a much more nuanced area and it really does depend a lot on your work, their practices, policies etc.
I think here, absent the Doctors medical assessment (although I am not a Doctor - having the conversation with your doctor about your concern of superficial swelling in a particular area combined with your chosen profession might be a Medical grounds...) - your best option would be to outline the following:

You have concerns that the side-effects of the Surgery (swelling) might impact your ability to do your job and the appropriateness of it all.
During your difference between when your Doctor says you are fit to work and the swelling decreasing, you can do XYZ alternative duties where the side-effect is not a concern
If you have PTO available, use that instead.

I think most Doctors - when told of the specific concern around swelling and your profession would be more than happy to extend the medical leave slip to where the swelling has gone down sufficiently - but assuming they wouldn't be - then your option is to discuss with HR and come up with a scenario that they are happy with.

The doctor can go to jail if he doesn't allow medical leave and the patient gets hurt due to returning to work. All doctors will err on caution because the patient is their responsibility. They're not going to side with the employer.

@Nelson: That doesn't mean they are going to lie on behalf of the employee, though; their professional reputation can be damaged by that too. If they think the employee really is malingering, any support will be lukewarm at best.

@keshlam There's no reason for the surgeon to lie about anything, and OP isn't asking anyone to lie either. Where are you getting that idea? OP haven't even spoken with a doctor about it yet. OP needs to be clear and upfront that a similar operation resulted in swelling, and also that their "HR has requested an exact return date". The doctor understands how HR works and it is extremely unlikely that he has any fondness of ridiculous HR behavior. The bottom line is, OP should be proactively working with the doctor to get the medical leave he needs, not try to get HR to do anything.

@nelson: We don't disagree. I've just seen a few too many questions over the decades where the goal was to pad the sick leave rather than to take needed recovery time. By all means take all the recovery time you legitimately need.

If one is still at risk, a doctor should certainly say so, and should explain what the patient's current constraints are. But that may not prohibit coming to work and performing other tasks. I think what bothers me is the phrase "despite being physically able/fit to work", which suggests that the asker is looking for a way to avoid having to perform even those reduced duties. That may just be a matter of phrasing and interpretation, admittedly.

When assessing fitness for work the doctor should definitely ask what kind of work OP is doing and make their assessment based on the particular job OP is trying to perform. An obvious example could be if you can't walk but are otherwise fit. Whether this makes you able to work or not depends on the job you have and a doctors medical exemption will account for that.

Assuming a US based healthcare system
Married to a doctor, not a doctor myself, not giving medical advice, follow at your own risk.
Be honest with your doctor and trust their decision with regards to returning to work. The doctor isn't beholden to your employer and faces SIGNIFICANTLY more risk for clearing a person to work too early, as opposed to being overly cautious with work clearance.
The human body is complex and takes a highly variable timeframe to recover from various injuries. I can pretty much guarantee your surgical discharge paperwork instructs you to notify the surgeons office (or hospital, etc.) of any swelling, redness, discomfort, or other signs that something may not be quite right post surgery.
Getting all that out of the way, HIPAA prevents your doctor from sharing your personal health information (PHI) without authorization. HIPAA Also prevents HR from sharing your PHI, should you authorize a release of the information to them. Your boss (the person handling your leave requests from the non-HR side, who typically also has the power to fire you) is likewise bound by HIPAA. Your random coworker who asks you how the surgery went is NOT bound by HIPAA, and is free to share whatever you share with them at their will.
With your doctor's guidance, I would share very little with your employer. The factual information that they need (and what they appear to be looking for) is as accurate a timeframe as possible for your absence. This will not require a disclosure of the procedure, the complications, specifics of why you are/are not able to return, and under what timeframe. What you should share is a statement from your doctor detailing that you were seen for 'a procedure', the date you were seen, and the current expected safe date to return to work. Note that complications are, well, complicated. That safe date may get pushed out if your discomfort or recovery take longer than anticipated to resolve.
If the surgeon does clear you to return prior to the 8 week timeframe elapsing, I would personally skip the above process and just shoot HR back an email stating that the recovery will require the full 8 weeks of leave you initially detailed. This does depend on your employers policy around medical leave. Read your employee handbook (or have HR send you a copy of the relevant section) to understand what you need to provide to have your leave approved. If you need a letter from the surgeon to have the full leave, you might just be SOL.
As for questions in the workplace as to swelling/redness/other physical signs of the procedure. Deflection ("How did you handle the discussion of advanced polynomials with student's like John/Sally, I don't seem to be reaching them effectively."), politely declining to answer ("I'm not comfortable with that question, can we keep our workplace discussions professional please?"), or even outright lying ("Oh, that swelling started happening when I was sedentary/bedridden after the procedure. The doctor said that's normal for post-op regardless of the procedure, and should go away with time"). Students will generally require a different approach on a student by student basis. You don't owe them an explanation, but if you feel compelled to provide one, keep the personal details as light as possible.
I wish you the best of luck and a speedy recovery.
